# Tab is not active after refresh page - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to show `profile` tab active after refreshing the page.But the tab is getting active before the page load and afterwards not active.

But I'm calling the `activeTab` function after `location.reload()` . 
Any Suggestions?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Generate', function(e) {
  alert('hello');
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 500);
    activeTab('profile');
  }, 2000);

});


function activeTab(tabID) {
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabID + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

```html
<button id="Generate">
      Click
    </button>
<p>
  &nbsp;
</p>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a working example.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Why would you reload the page and expect the tab to be active? you need cookies or localStorage or something on the URL to identify the active status after a reload. Why do you reload at all?

Comment: Actually, in my code, i was generating the invoice as PDF and reload the page and showing the tab which contains all PDF list. So I can't share the full code that's why I have asked for the sample code.

Comment: @eulloa : http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2721/ this is sample demo which i was trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/0erervmb/

```js
activeTab = function(tabID) {
  $('#myTab ul li a[href="#' + tabID + '"]').click();
}

$(document).on('click', '#Generate', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 500);
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', 'profile');
    activeTab('profile');
  }, 2000);

});

$('#myTab').tabs();

if( localStorage.getItem('activeTab') != null){
 activeTab(localStorage.getItem('activeTab'));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="Generate">
      Click
    </button>
<p>
  &nbsp;
</p>
<div id="myTab">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Points to be noted**

- I've modified `HTML` a bit.
- Please add `$('#myTab').tabs();`
- Used `localStorage` for last activated tab after reload.

Second update https://jsfiddle.net/0erervmb/1/

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Generate', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 500);
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', 'profile');
  }, 2000);

});
```

Just remove `activeTab('profile');`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's making the tab active even before refreshing the page. How to avoid this?

Comment: Did you observe that at the first of page loads why profile tab is active home should be active right? then after refresh, profile should be active